# React native Mailer (RNMail) - issue with attaching file

Tags: react-native

i am currently trying to send an email from the users device via my react native app.
The process to do so is simple. The user fills out some input fields, selects a picture (new or from gallery) and proceeds to send it via email.
According to the documentation of the module an absolute file path to the picture is required.

The file path which I get looks as following:

```
file:///Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/909705DC-D5…119-75CC009FFA5C/Documents/images/6EC7EAA7-0D37-4909-ABC4-B5DE250ED968.jpg
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Exception '-[MFMailComposeInternalViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.' was thrown while invoking mail on target RNMail with params (
        {
        attachment =         {
            name = Name;
            path = "file:///Users/zser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/909705DC-D5…119-75CC009FFA5C/Documents/images/6EC7EAA7-0D37-4909-ABC4-B5DE250ED968.jpg";
            type = jpg;
        };
        body = "<h1>Content</h1>";
        isHTML = 1;
        recipients =         (
            "reiceiver@mail.com"
        );
        subject = subject;
    },
    25
)
```

Is something wrong with this path?

Heres the basic code that should accept the file as attachement:

```
Mailer.mail({
      subject: 'Subject',
      recipients: ['receiver@mail.com'],
      body: `<h1>Content</h1>`,
      isHTML: true, // iOS only, exclude if false
      attachment: {
        path: that.state.absolute_path,  // The absolute path of the file from which to read data.
        type: 'jpg',   // Mime Type: jpg, png, doc, ppt, html, pdf
        name: 'Ladunek',   // Optional: Custom filename for attachment
      }
    }, (error, event) => {
        if(error) {
          AlertIOS.alert('Error', 'Niestety mail nie zostal wyslany. Prosze przeslac manualnie mail na : receiver@mail.com');
        }
    })
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently removing `'file:///'` from the absolute path fixed the issue.